# Excel 365 in Teams/Sharepoint does not open the correct revision in one of my shared files (only one person in my team)

Tags: excel

It is a very difficult to explain the issue, neither the IT ea in my company is finding the problem. 
We store in Sharepoint three .xlsx files that I and my team access and update every day. 
One of the guys has a problem in only one of the files, when he opens the file he always shows an old revision such a week before. If I or any other inside the team open the same file in Teams/Sharepoint it shows correctly!
Is there some buffer or other thing storage in his computer which doesn't permit the file open correctly?

Comment: Try asking on https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com.

Comment: thanks @jsheeran, I've just done :-) Cheers!!